# How to get TimeZone by selecting it's Identifiers in swiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, timezone, pickerview

I am new to Swift.. I am implementing Timezones identifiers in my pickerView. It's almost done but I want to get Abbreviations and related data when I select particular PickerView, But I am unable to do so
Please help me out if somebody know.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        //        store = timezone[row]
        if pickerView == pickerOne {
            let storeTime = self.timeZoneIdentifiers[row]
            timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: storeTime)!
            selectLabel.text = "\(timeZone)"
            
        } else if pickerView == pickerTwo {
            let storeLocale = self.language[row]
            locale = Locale.init(identifier: storeLocale)
            selectLabelTwo.text = "\(locale)"
        }
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I have added now

Comment: Hi.  I see you're new here.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular: *"DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question."*. Thanks.